# What does nchar(substitute(a + b + c)) actually count?

Tags: r

I was toying around with `substitute` and can't quite figure out what the result of `nchar(substitute(a + b + c))` actually is? The result is

```
nchar(substitute(a + b + c))
[1] 1 5 1
```

What exactly does it count? I thought that the middle term is just the number of elements of that expression. But what does the following count then and what do the other 1's stand for?

```
nchar(substitute(a + b))
[1] 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can check from converting to `character`

```
v1 <- as.character(substitute(a + b + c))
v1 
#[1] "+"     "a + b" "c"    

nchar(v1)
#[1] 1 5 1
```

counts also the space to give the number of characters.

whereas

```
as.character(substitute(a + b))
#[1] "+" "a" "b"
```

is one character length for each of the elements.

Comment: thanks that does answer my question. as a follow up: why is the expression split like that? I get  `as.character(substitute(a + b))` because `a + b` is basically `+(a, b)` but why the other split `[1] "+"     "a + b" "c"`?

Comment: @ManuelS  When you have two terms, it is `"+", "a", "b"` but with more than 2 terms, the second term should have the remaining `+`. You can check `as.character(substitute(a + b + c + d))`  I don't know the exact reason why it got split like that.

Comment: It's because `+` is a left-to-right operator.  So `a + b + c` is equivalent to  `"+"(a + b, c)`.